Volterra integral operator is completly continuous, given that its kernel is continuous
Prove that Volterra integral operator on $C[a,b]$ is completly continuous, knowing its kernel $K:C[a,b]\times[a,b]\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
I used this definition, the operator $V:C[a,b] \rightarrow C[a,b]$ defined by $x \longmapsto Vx$, $Vx(t) := \int_{a}^{t} K(t,s,x(s)) ds$ is the Volterra integral operator with kernel $K$.
To prove that the Volterra integral operator $V$ is completely continuous, I thought I need to show that $V$ maps bounded sets in $C[a,b]$ to relatively compact sets in $C[a,b]$. So I checked the continuity and boundedness of $Vx$, then equicontinuity of $V(B)$, where $B\subset C[a,b]$ and $V(B)=\{Vx : x\in B\}$. What do you think? is there anything else I should do for the proof to be more consistent?
